Remove attribute label for variable products in Woocommerce Single product page
I can "Hide" the attribute label using this code:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'remove_attribute_label');
function remove_attribute_label() {
    return "";
}

It works fine, however, formatting keeps my variations choices slightly to the right instead of aligning left. (see Image:
Standard and Extended License radio buttons not aligned left
The Standard and Extended License radio buttons are not aligned left, and my goal is to have them aligned left.
Thanks for any help.

Your function removes the label of the product attribute by replacing it with an empty string. Have you tried applying CSS styling to your radio buttons, or the wrapper/container? You need to inspect radio buttons by: Right-click on them and select "Inspect" or "Inspect Element" from the context menu. This will open the browser’s developer tools and highlight the HTML code. There you can also see styling and other properties.

I added some CSS, based on Richard comment, to change the right padding from 1em to 0em, and it worked:
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .variations .label {
    padding-right: 0em;
    text-align: left; 
}

The radio buttons are now aligned left.
